# RabbitMQ PHP for dynamic message updates

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange, php-amqp

I am learning RabbitMQ and thought of using it for giving "dynamic message" updates to users very much like facebook give dynamic feeds from friends.

**My Idea was :**

1. Whenever a user is created I will create a queue having name is user's userId so queue name could be "`100_message_queue`" (userId_message_queue).
2. Producer will push all updates in this queue.
3. From client side (javascript) , it will call a REST API like "`GET http://example.com/getliveupdates/100`" , then I will fetch all new updates from `100_message_queue` and send it as response.

I read RabbitMQ php tutorials but cannot figure out how this is possible ? Moreover consumer runs forever so its seems I cannot make any REST request. It is giving me timeout.

Any idea how to implement this kind of structure ?

Thanks

Comment: So you're polling your queue, but you'd rather a server-push?

Answer (score 1):

As you planning to deliver that messages to the web client, I would recommend to look on [MQTT](http://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html) and [STOMP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) with [Web STOMP](http://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) RabbitMQ plugins. For you it should be perfect solution to employ their power over WebSocket. And it gives you realtime messaging, which is always a pro and probably what you want.

As to dealing with running forever consumers:

If you are using `php-amqp` extension you can set `read_timeout` option to some small values, say 1 (sec), so when consumer get all messages from queue it will wait for 1 sec. more for new messages and then throw an exception (I guess AMQPConnectionException, ugly solution, but this is how it's done for now).

Alternatively, you can `AMQPQueue::get` messages from queue until there will be no messages left.

With `php-amqplib` things should be the same, at least idea still the same: limit consumer to wait for new messages by time or get messages from queue in iterative manner.